# How to integrate Wordpress with moodle 2.5

Tags: wordpress, connect, moodle, integrate

I'm trying to integrate wordpress with moodle 2.5 , what I want to do exactly is: I want that the  users login in wordpress and from there they can link to moodle, also I'd like wordpress to use moodle's users. Is it possible? Anyone could help me please?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Moodle can act as an openid provider, so you should be able to login to Wordpress using Moodle account.

Please refer: https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=local_openid_idp

Comment: I'm using it, and I'm using http://wordpress.org/plugins/external-db-auth-reloaded/ in wordpress.. .but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still finding a solution for your issue then, there are a number of plugins which does this job of integration between Moodle and WordPress.
You could use Edwiser Bridge a plugin for such integration it works well even syncs courses in Moodle to WordPress.
It is a free plugin which should fulfill your need.

Comment: Edwiser Bridge for Single Sign On is not free: https://edwiser.org/bridge/extensions/single-sign-on/